# Getting a BSOD and wonder RAM sticks might be the cause? Is a memory test guarantee 100% assurance?

Tags: windows-7, memory

I’m using Windows 7 (64-bit) 16GB RAM (2x8GB RAM sticks).

Yesterday I got a blue screen while using my computer (Chrome browsing mostly).

[image]

For checking that it is not a memory problem - I ran 
“*Windows memory diagnostic tool*” (which comes with Windows).

**Question**

Regarding RAM sticks only:

Windows memory diagnostic tool showed no errors. Can I conclude that the RAM sticks are fine? Or are there any other errors that are not recognized by this tool?

Comment: what where you developing in Visual studio? If you are developing something e.g. in c++ that has to do with interrupts, the reason might rather be somethign like that.

Comment: @TechImpossible Valid point. I'm just using web stuff. no unsafe operations.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Incidentally, from my own experience, the most likely cause of `0a` BSOD is overclocking, followed by bad driver, followed by bad power supply, followed by bad PCI/PCI-e card or USB device, followed by bad motherboard, followed by bad RAM. I would try troubleshooting things in that order. I know that doesn't answer your question but hopefully it'll help you approach your troubleshooting the right way.

Comment: Your BSOD [indicates a kernel-level segfault/null-pointer access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Specifically, an instruction at address `0xFFFFF800030E518F` attempted to `write` to memory address `0x0000000000000080` while at IRQL `2`. This _could_ occur because of a bit-flip in memory, but smells to me more like a driver bug. The one time this occurred to me involved a bad Wifi driver, which I downgraded. Whoever supplied the instruction at the `0xFFFFF8...` address is the guilty party and should be disabled.

Comment: share the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump

Comment: @magicandre1981 Indeed.  Now it's 07:50. At 09:00 - when I'm at work - I'll do it ! Thanks !

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'm here but the folder is empty. anyway I changed the settings start working now. [see here](http://i.imgur.com/vUjArlS.png)

Comment: Agreed with @IwillnotexistIdonotexist - this definitely seems like a driver bug.  Try running [WhoCrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed) to get more info from your dump file.  I've seen this on newer mobos with various older PCI hardware.  Also bad USB drivers for older devices that don't like running on XHCI, etc.

Comment: I appreciate how this had to be a picture given the computer wasn't in the state to take a screenshot =P

Comment: I agree with @IwillnotexistIdonotexist - it smells of driver bug - see one of the answers below that talks about using WinDbg to diagnose. If you suspect RAM, I will say that I've had very bad RAM that RAM tests couldn't diagnose. If you start getting lots of crashes, a good test is whether or not your computer crashes after that stick is removed from the computer (aka, swap out your sticks one at a time). It can take quite a lot of waiting, but it works.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, the fact that the Windows memory diagostic tool passes does not mean your RAM is definitely fine. A much more thorough tool is [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/). This tool often finds memory problems that do not show up in other tests. You'll want to run an extended test at least overnight.

Comment: Woooo... overnight ?

Comment: He is correct, a software test can never give you a 100% guarantee, even memtest can't, as ther are many more factors that can lead to bit errors that a software can't emulate, like slight current variations and other things in that range.

Comment: Well, if you see test failures immediately, that'd answer your question. But I would want more than a single pass on extended test run before I was certain. RAM sticks that are right on the line may pass a single run and fail subsequent tests.

Comment: Upon buying RAM, first thing I do is memtest it for at least 24 hours if not 48.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay Are you sure that's necessary? I've never run memtests on my RAM, and only do so in response to issues that appear, of which I've only had one in eight years.

Comment: Better to test and not need than to endure seemingly "random" crashes for the lifetime of your PC. I bought expensive Corsair RAM and lo and behold, it failed memtest after 24 hours. My PC is a rackmount, and I really don't want to drag that 50 pound chassis out after installing it.

Comment: **BE CAREFUL**: There are some versions that give **false negatives (false errors)** on the **7th test (something related to random numbers)**. Use the latest version. The issue is fixed on those. Buggy versions are included on Ubuntu ISOs. I'm not sure if they updated their version or not.

Comment: @TechImpossible is right, this happend to me not so long ago. I had faulty RAM and all software testing suites I used said nothing was wrong. RAM is so cheap these days that its easier just to buy a stick and see if you BSOD.

Comment: @Soapy the problem is, with faulty RAM you don't get a BSOD immediately after putting it in! You might get BSOD seemingly random, or maybe the results of some calculations are just wrong. Or files you save are faulty. If it was "put in faulty RAM, get BSOD" there wouldn't be any test tools to begin with.But with todays prices I use ECC memory whenever possible, especially because I like the ZFS filesystem and wouldn't dare to use it without ECC RAM.

Comment: Memtest86+ is the better version of the two (Memtest86 vs. Memtest86+)

Comment: @SnakeDoc When I last ran Memtest86+, it froze after a few minutes. I googled that issue and it has to do with version 5.01 and multicore machines. So be careful what version you use.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Interesting - I've never run into that issue. Memtest86+ was a fork of Memtest86 after that project stagnated for many years. Now it seems both projects are more-or-less active. Memtest86+ remains 100% free to use (even in commercial/professional situations), while Memtest86 now has commercial (paid) offerings for those types of users (IT professionals and not just home use).

Comment: @Emrakul Yes, I tend to only run when I have issues too. Even for my servers (which admittedly do a self memory diag on boot). RAM rarely fails... just like CPU's rarely fail (but when they do, it's usually in spectacular fashion). Most common problems causing BSOD's are viruses, bad drivers, faulty HDD, or faulty mobo.

Comment: If you're using non-ECC RAM, be sure to test each stick one at a time. If you test all your RAM and it fails, you don't know which stick is the culprit. Also, wear electro-static protection.

Comment: @user13743 Memtest86+ tells you which slot failed... so you can test them all at once.

Comment: You want to run Memtest86 and/or Memtest86+ before booting the computer after adding the RAM.  Otherwise, you risk writing data with errors to the disk.  I bought some RAM, had intermittent crashes (usually just software errors).  After a few weeks I finally tested the RAM.  Once I replaced the RAM I still had errors, until I re-imaged the system.

Answer (score 9):

> Windows memory diagnostic tool showed no errors. Can I conclude that the RAM sticks are fine? Or are there any other errors that are not recognized by this tool?

No you can't, I don't know of any software tests for RAM that are 100% infallible.

If the BSOD is a one off I'd put it down to a power issue, if it occurs more often I'd start looking at hardware and drivers.

Your error message could be related to drivers, check if you have updated any of your drivers recently. With errors like this the Microsoft site has a lot of troubleshooting information on specific errors. I won't go into them because your question is just about RAM, but I suggest you check out MS.

Answer (score 9):

This error indicates that some driver at the kernel level attempted to write to paged virtual memory (that means *slow* virtual memory that is baked by a hard disk's paged file) during interrupt request that was meant to be processed really fast. This is most likely a software fault.

Windows has several interrupt request levels (more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/hardware/dn550976) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/doronh/archive/2010/02/02/what-is-irql.aspx)). Some IRQLa are designed to handle system critical stuff like power mode changes, CPU clock ticks etc. The higher the level - the less stuff a driver can do. For example during a power failure a driver cannot access any memory - it's too slow for that.

If you want to troubleshoot this and pin-point a faulty driver you'll need to open memory dump that was collected right after the crash. You can double check the location of the dump in `System Properties > Advanced > Startup and Recovery > Settings > Dump file`. See the picture

[image]

You can then open dump file with tools, such as WinDbg (download the right version for your Windows) and in WinDbg you can run `analyze -v` on the dump. This should tell you which driver is likely to be at fault.